# Not able to insert items on my linked list, head always NULL

Tags: c++, algorithm, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am new to C++ and attempting to create a single linked list data structure holding integer values.

I am having issues with the insert method, it seems like that the head reference I am passing to the function is always NULL (maybe I am passing in its value by mistake).

I would like to use the following insert method:

insert(L,x): where L is the pointer to the first element of the list and x the integer value to insert.

This is my linked list hpp file:

```
class LinkedList{

private:
 struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
 };
 Node* head;

public:
 LinkedList();
 ~LinkedList();

 void insert(Node* _head,int _value);
 int lenght(Node* _head);
 Node* getHead();
};
```

This is my linked list cpp file:

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(){
 head = NULL;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList(){

}

void LinkedList::insert(LinkedList::Node* _head,int _value){
 Node* temp = new Node;
 temp->data = _value;
 temp->next = NULL;

 // _head is NULL every time this function is called

 if(_head == NULL){
    _head = temp;
 }
 else{
    while(_head->next != NULL){
        _head = _head->next;
    }
    _head->next = temp;
 }
}

int LinkedList::lenght(LinkedList::Node* _head){
 int count = 0;

 while(_head!=NULL){
    count++;
    _head=_head->next;
 }
 return count;
}


LinkedList::Node* LinkedList::getHead(){
 return head;
}
```

This is the main file:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

 LinkedList list;

 list.insert(list.getHead(), 3);
 list.insert(list.getHead(), 4);
 list.insert(list.getHead(), 5);
 list.insert(list.getHead(), 6);

 cout << list.lenght(list.getHead()); //This prints out 0 elements 

 return 0;
}
```

The code runs fine but the number of elements in the list is always 0.
It seems like that the _head inside the insert function always points to null.

I hope I described the issue well, thanks for your help in advance.

Andrea

Comment: you are moving the actual head of the list, `_head` member variable. Keep a copy to the head of the list and use a temporary variable to iterate, like `LinkedList::Node* iterator = _head`

Comment: Insert() does not allow you to return the created head and it uses a copy of the head member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The head node is always equal to nullptr because the function `insert` deals with a copy of the original head returned by the function `getHead`. So changing the copy does not influence on the value of the original head.

These member functions

```
void insert(Node* _head,int _value);
```

and

```
Node* getHead();
```

do not make sense. Why is the private data member head returned to the user of the list? In this case the user is able directly to change data in the list bypassing the public interface.

Declare the function `insert` like

```
void insert( int value );
```

and remove entirely the function `getHead`.

In this case the function `insert` (which is better to rename at least like `append` taking into account the used algorithm) can be defined like

```
void LinkedList::insert( int value )
{
    Node *temp = new Node { value, nullptr };

    Node **tail = &head;

    while ( *tail ) tail = &( *tail )->next;

    *tail = temp;
}
```

And in main the function can be called like

```
list.insert( 3 );
list.insert( 4 );
list.insert( 5 );
list.insert( 6 );
```

If it is a requirement of the assignment to have the function getHead then at least delare the function like

```
Node * & getHead();
```

In this case the function insert will look like

```
void LinkedList::insert( Node * &node, int value )
{
    Node *temp = new Node { value, nullptr };

    Node **tail = &node;

    while ( *tail ) tail = &( *tail )->next;

    *tail = temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
if (_head == NULL) {
    _head = temp;
}
```

You are assigning the new "first" element to the local copy of `head`, and not to the actual `head`. Fix that and it works:

```
if (_head == NULL) {
    this->head = temp; // "this" isn't strictly needed, but it signals that head is a member and not a local.
}
```